# bookmarklet functionality missing in Firefox Android?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, brave-browser

I am trying out [bookmarklet](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarklets-perform-common-web-page-tasks) functionality on a mobile platform (Android 10).

The bookmarklet is named `test` and points to the code

```js
javascript:alert('boo')
```

**How I test:**

- Save the bookmarklet as described above to the bookmarks folder;
- Go to some random website;
- In the address bar, start typing `test`;
- The browser will recognize the bookmark and offer it in a menu;
- Click it.

**Results:**

- In [Brave for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brave.browser&hl=en) (Chrome-based) the alert window appears as expected;
- in [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en_US) absolutely nothing happens.

**Question:**
Is this intentional on Mozilla's part and/or expected or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out bookmarklets do indeed fail to work on the latest Android Firefox. This was pointed out on the [Mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1301329#answer-1344552) after I asked, with a link to the relevant [github issue](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/2871).

Comment: On iOS they are even intentionally disabled :( ([github ticket #5626](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/issues/5626))

Comment: Does this work for you now? The issue is closed but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox android doesn't let you run Bookmarklets the traditional way, But, there is a workaround, you can call Bookmarklet from the address bar,

First, you have to manually create a Bookmarklet by editing it,

For example, `javascript:alert('foo');` and name it.

Then, on the page you waant to run this, search for the bookmarklet name in the address bar, and click on it.

[image: Bookmarklet on Android]

Below Tutorial might be helpful.

https://paul.kinlan.me/use-bookmarklets-on-chrome-on-android/